# How to enable h2c in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, http2

Is there a way to enable h2c aka HTTP2 cleartext in Nginx 1.9.5 onward?

I've tried using h2 over TLs in https://chronic101.xyz and it works, however I would like to implement h2c on port 80 as well.

Thanks,

chrone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be as simple as adding **http2** in the end of your **listen** directive.

Example:

```
server {
    listen 80 http2;
```

However, keep in mind that most browsers do not support unencrypted HTTP/2, and so will still serve content as HTTP/1.1.

Comment: Whoa @Gabriel Hautclocq, thanks it finally works on Nginx 1.10. :D

Comment: Worth noting is that nginx does not (as of when I'm writing this message) support running h2c on the same port as http/1.1. I.e. it can't magically switch between the protocols.