# how can I use http2.0 without ssl on linux with nginx

Tags: nginx, http2

I want to send or accept http2.0, but I don`t want use SSL, because I want capture the bag for the study。
I had search some knowledge, that say nginx can use http2.0 without SSL, SSL is a must for the browser
so I think I can use postman or curl and other serverce for send reques.
now, I want to know how can I deploy the nginx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable h2c in Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108188/how-to-enable-h2c-in-nginx)